# Windows logo key not working in VMware

Tags: windows, vmware-player

I've tried both Windows 7 x64 and Windows 8 x64.

VMware tools are installed. The key itself does nothing, while shortcuts produce an error sound. Using the on-screen keyboard, I've verified the key is actually supposed to do something.

How can I make the key work? It's currently cumbersome to get back to the Start screen on Windows 8.

Comment: Does it work for you with other VMWare images/OS's? What's the Host OS?  Which VMWare product/version are you using?

Comment: I'll have try a different OS. Host is Windows 7 x64, using VMware Player 4.0.3 build-703057 (no updates available).

Comment: @techie007 I've installed a Windows 7 guest, doesn't work in there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my Windows key wasn't even working in the host OS. After a bit of searching, I discovered what this switch on my Logitech G110 keyboard is for.

> **Game/desktop mode**
>   No accidental interruptions—you can disable the Windows/Context Menu
>   keys when you play.

Comment: You saved my night :)

Answer (score 0):

i am not pretty sure but try this, it may work, while on the screen with your guest OS on, trying locking and unlocking your host OS with **Ctrl+Alt+Del**,sometimes it works, not always....i was facing the same problem while using windows 8 as guest and windows 7 ultimate x64 as host on my vmware workstation 8, got this while just pressing random keys in irritation....